# Tactical RPG in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I feel as if I have learned enough C# over the years for me to attempt my first game. I already know the limitations of C# (will only work on Widows/Xbox), but I still want to use it since it is the only one I know.

Recently I was searching online and found out about the XNA framework, which is some sort of gaming library collection. My question is, will it allow me to do the following:

- Create a turn based RPG game where characters move on squares, just like the Xcom for example
- Render cartoony 2D graphics in [this style](http://www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/526564-the-binding-of-isaac-windows-screenshot-isaac-uses-the-magnet.png)
- Save/load to disk
- Distribute through Steam

Thanks for any potential answers :).

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes, and I don't know.  I personally, have made a tactical RPG in XNA, so I know it can be done.  Not sure about steam though

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Do you have a screenshot I could look at? Maybe get a feel?

Comment: I have a couple of XNA games on my Steam account, no problems.

Comment: Can you post their names please?

Comment: Bastion is a game on Steam that was made in XNA

Comment: Wow really? I played that game, it was awesome! Thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing the first three is very straightforward.

XNA is designed for distribution through the [XNA Creators Club](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/) to be distrubuted via XBOX Live Indie Games.

Distributing through Steam may be possible, but could also be a bit trickier, as its not the built in distribution mechanism.  That being said, [Steam does accept games built with XNA](http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/FAQ.php), so this should be possible.

Comment: Yes, for XBox games. But PC games written in XNA can absolutely be distributed through Steam.

Comment: Joel do you have any information on this? I do believe you but I would like to be 100% sure it can be done.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper The whole point of steam is that the mechanism for building the game is irrelevant.  You pretty much just need an executable.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper Just edited with a link to their FAQ :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Very helpful. It seems I will need to make some sort of wrapper class for their API since it is written in C++ however.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually done such a project in XNA before

- When I made my project in XNA, I drew a grid of tiles, and had a state machine, and had 7 or so major states which involved the flow of the game.  Beginning state, first action selection - moving animation - second action selection - attacking animation - damage resolution, etc.
- Your graphics can be just about whatever you want, I believe that XNA's built in graphics engine supports multiple image formats like .png for instance.  And you can also animate your images by using a spritesheet.  (you might want to google how to use a spritesheet).  but you might have to find an artist to do them.
- Yes  you can do that with c# or just about any language out there.  Just write to the file whenever you feel like saving, and you can load from it in your `LoadContent` handler

Comment: Can I see the finished product?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper In a few hours I might be able to dig it up for you, but I can't make any promises.  It's been a while

Comment: It's ok, just want to get a glimpse :).